# Defining custom checkbox style

Tags: wpf

Good afternoon all,

I am currently trying to write a custom checkbox control in WPF that simply reverses the direction of the checkmark. Using the code below I can do it on a particular control.

```
                        <CheckBox.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
                                <Setter Property="FlowDirection" 
                                  Value="LeftToRight"/>
                            </Style>
                        </CheckBox.Resources>
```

However, I don't want to repeat this code 50+ times so I was hoping to get some help overriding the checkbox control to work exactly the same but just with a reversed checkmark. I have not played around with overriding WPF controls at all yet so any additional explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the style with the rest of your styles and resources at the application level (in App.xaml's resources.)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
            <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

This style applies to all checkboxes in scope because `x:Key` isn't specified.

Comment: I just noticed this but it looks like in the designer the checkboxes have successfully redrawn correctly but when I actually compile and run my program they are still the wrong direction. I am pretty confused on what could be happening dynamically to cause this.

Comment: Never mind I was able to get it to work by just applying it to the window.